# How to dowloa file from safeUrlImpl in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hello I am not able to download file from above code in ts file.
I also want to know what is bypasssecurity means in sanitizing file.
If possible can anybody tell me how to download any file excluding jpg/png file in angular.

Here is what i code before.

```
if(this.nonImageFileList.length>0){
      for(let i =0 ;i<this.nonImageFileList.length;i++){
        console.log(this.nonImageFileList[i])
        const downloadedFile = new Blob([this.nonImageFileList[i].data]);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            document.body.appendChild(a); 
            a.download = this.nonImageFileList.fileName;
            a.setAttribute('download',this.nonImageFileList.fileName);
            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(downloadedFile);
            a.target = '_blank';
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is screen shot of console log.
[Why safeUrlImppl gets append on click of download it gets downloded in undefined.txt format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywkvb.png)

Comment: in which browser you are doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your work is very close. Your correctly provided the `URL.createObjectURL()` to the href, but not to the download attribute. Assigning the filename does not work because the browser is expecting a URL to download from, even if it was created locally.

Also, there is no need to assign to both `a.download` and `a.setAttribute('download')`, this is redundant.

A working version of your code would look like this:

```js
if(this.nonImageFileList.length > 0) {
  for(let i = 0; i < this.nonImageFileList.length; i++) {
    // Create a URL from the file
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([this.nonImageFileList[i].data]);

    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    document.body.appendChild(a); 

    // Assign the URL to the href and download attributes
    a.download = url;
    a.href = url;

    a.target = '_blank';
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
}
```